# Having trouble with this sequelize syntax error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, sequelize.js

This is my error, "Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near "WHERE""

```
let toQuery = ' 
SELECT 
    "Discount".*, 
    "Business.BusinessImages"."url" AS "Business.BusinessImages.url",
    "Business.BusinessImages"."id" AS "Business.BusinessImages.id",
    "Business.BusinessImages"."createdAt" AS "Business.BusinessImages.createdAt",
    "Business.BusinessImages"."updatedAt" AS "Business.BusinessImages.updatedAt",
    "Business.BusinessImages"."height" AS "Business.BusinessImages.height",
    "Business.BusinessImages"."width" AS "Business.BusinessImages.width",
    "Business.BusinessImages"."primary" AS "Business.BusinessImages.primary",
    "Business.BusinessImages"."thumb" AS "Business.BusinessImages.thumb",
    "Business.BusinessImages"."BusinessId" AS "Business.BusinessImages.BusinessId",
    "Business.BusinessLocations"."id" AS "Business.BusinessLocations.id",
    "Business.BusinessLocations"."physAddress" AS "Business.BusinessLocations.physAddress",
    "Business.BusinessLocations"."physCity" AS "Business.BusinessLocations.physCity",
    "Business.BusinessLocations"."physState" AS "Business.BusinessLocations.physState",
    "Business.BusinessLocations"."physZip" AS "Business.BusinessLocations.physZip",
    "Business.BusinessLocations"."latitude" AS "Business.BusinessLocations.latitude", "Business.BusinessLocations"."longitude" AS "Business.BusinessLocations.longitude" 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        "Discount"."id", "Discount"."offerdetails",
        "Discount"."offertitle",
        "Discount"."offerType",
        "Discount"."createdAt",
        "Discount"."updatedAt",
        "Discount"."BusinessId",
        "Business"."id" AS "Business.id",
        "Business"."name" AS "Business.name",
        "Business"."description" AS "Business.description",
        "Business"."URL" AS "Business.URL" 
    FROM 
        "Discounts" AS "Discount" 
    INNER JOIN 
        "Businesses" AS "Business" 
            ON "Discount"."BusinessId" = "Business"."id" 
            AND "Business"."active" = true 
            AND "Business"."approved" = true 
    WHERE 
        "Discount"."deleted" = false 
        AND "Discount"."active" = true 
    LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0) AS "Discount" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "BusinessImages" AS "Business.BusinessImages" 
        ON "Business.id" = "Business.BusinessImages"."BusinessId" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "BusinessLocations" AS "Business.BusinessLocations" 
    ON "Business.id" = "Business.BusinessLocations"."BusinessId"; '

     console.log('#############################', toQuery);
      toQuery = toQuery + ' WHERE "Discount"."'  + discountThis.getSearchVector()  
      + '" @@ plainto_tsquery(\'english\', ' + query + ')';
```

Im sorry I don't know how to format this better, there is one "Where" in the first toQuery but I've tried modifying that query to remove that where statement and the issue persists with the same error. Ive narrowed it down to the second toQuery below the console.log. This code I've posted is part of a search I am trying to make using Postgres built in tsvector function.

I have tried my best to read the documentation as well as other code examples on here and on GitHub but I am lost as to what this error is. I have been primarily following another example in my codebase that's completed and running properly and it has no issues and my syntax is identical. Any advice and guidance will be greatly appreciated as I've been stuck here for a few days and Im feeling pretty demotivated.

Comment: You've got a semicolon in the end of the `toQuery` string

Comment: This doesn't look like it has a lot to do with react or sequelize? What system gives you that error? Looks like a database error: the postgres log should contain the entire sql command that had the syntax error, so you don't have to dig around your js code.

Comment: The semicolon isn't the issue. The output is the same error with or without it.

Comment: How can I access the Postgres log?